# Add shortcut to BBEdit submenu

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, bbedit

Is there a way to add a shortcut to the Markup/Tidy/Reflow Document submenu in BBEdit?

Answer (score 2):

- BBEdit → Preferences → Menus → Menu
  key equivalents and item visibility:
  → Markup → Tidy → Reflow Document… →
  Set Key…

And another, more generic method - not sure about other system language versions:

- Apple → Preferencje systemowe… → Mysz i klawiatura → Skróty klawiszowe → + → Program: BBedit, Nazwa menu: Reflow Document…, Skrót klawiaturowy: [whatever]